# Calling generic function with two different generic arguments still compiles

Tags: java, generics, compilation, compiler-errors

How is it possible that following code even compiles? As far as I can see the count function is called with two different types, yet compiler doesn't complain and happily compiles this code.

```
public class Test {
        public static <T> int count(T[] x,T y){
                int count = 0;
                for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++){
                        if(x[i] == y) count ++;
                }
                return count;  
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Integer [] data = {1,2,3,1,4};
                String value = "1";
                int r =count(data,value);
                System.out.println( r + " - " + value);
        }
}
```

Comment: You have to understand that generics in Java are just a visual trick.  Through the compiler the types get erased down to Object.  Google "Java type erasure" to find the dirty details.

Comment: Indeed. I knew more or less what was happening, but I wanted to know why. I realized now that as you said, it (generics) is "just a visual trick" (I'd even call it dirty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the `T` is useless. You can change the signature to `public static int count(Object[] x, Object y)` without any effect on what arguments the compiler will let it accept. (You can see that the signature for `Arrays.fill()` uses that as the signature.)

If we consider the simpler case, where you just have arguments of type `T`, you can see that, since any instance of `T` is also an instance of its superclasses, `T` can always to be inferred to be its upper bound, and it will still accept the same argument types as before. Thus we can get rid of `T` and use its upper bound (in this case `Object`) instead.

Arrays in Java work the same way: arrays are covariant, which means that if `S` is a subclass of `T`, `S[]` is a subclass of `T[]`. So the same argument as above applies -- if you just have arguments of type `T` and `T[]`, `T` can be replaced by its upper bound.

(Note that this does not apply to generic types, which are not covariant or contravariant: `List<S>` is not a subtype of `List<T>`.)

Answer (score 7):

`T` gets coerced upwards to `Object`.  The `Integer[]` can be upcasted to `Object[]`, and the `String` gets upcasted to `Object`, and it typechecks.

Comment: In addition to this: the variable `r` is indeed a primitive type (not an object), but auto-boxing gets involved here, so it works :) .

Answer (score 2):

If you change your call to:

```
int r = Test.<Integer>count(data, value);
```

You will see the compiler complain.

Answer (score 1):

By passing two objects at once you are putting up too many constraints on `T`. This "forces" the compiler to infer `Object`. Luckily there's a simple workaround -- only pass one object. The following will produce the expected error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    String value = "1";
    int r = count(value).in(data);
    System.out.println(r + " - " + value);
}

public static <T> Counter<T> count(T obj) {
    return new Counter<T>(obj);
}

public static class Counter<T> {
    private final T obj;

    Counter(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public int in(T[] array) {
        return in(Arrays.asList(array));
    }

    public int in(Iterable<? extends T> iterable) {
        int count = 0;
        for (T element : iterable) {
            if (element == obj) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't really interested in making the code work (I know it's ugly). I mostly wanted to know *why* it even compiled. Interesting workaround though :-)

Comment: this is a very clever solution!

Answer (score 0):

Types are not so different - both are subclasses of java.lang.Object. So compiler assumes T is Object in this case.