# Java Generics, how to enforce two arguments of a method that extend a superclass to have a same type?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have a class hierarchy as follow:

```
class Vehicle;
class Car extends Vehicle;
class Plane extends Vehicle;
```

I have a function which compares the two object

```
public <T extends Vehicle> generateDiff(T original, T copy)
```

At compile time, the method above guarantees the two objects is `Vehicle`, but it cannot make sure the types of the two object are the same.

```
generateDiff(new Car(), new Car()); //OK
generateDiff(new Plane(), new Plane()); //OK
generateDiff(new Car(), new Plane()); //WRONG
```

Can I achive this at compile time using Generics?

P.s: currently, I've implemented it will throw exception if the `Class` of two objects are not the same. But I'm not satisfied with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can (kind of)!

The type `T` is being [inferred](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) from the arguments, but you can specify the type:

```
MyClass.<Car>generateDiff(new Car(), new Plane()); // generates a compile error
```

Without the typing the method, the type `T` is inferred to be the narrowest class that satisfies the bounds as used, so for parameters `Car` and `Plane`, the narrowest type that will work is `Vehicle`, so these two lines are equivalent:

```
generateDiff(new Car(), new Plane()); // type is inferred as Vehicle
MyClass.<Vehicle>generateDiff(new Car(), new Plane());
```

The above code assumes the `generateDiff()` is a static method. If it's an instance method, you could type your class and have that type used in your method.

Answer (score 6):

Once you get that deep into it, it gets a bit abstract. You would have to provide the class type for the function as well (see below). If you want to enforce such behavior, I would recommend writing separate methods that accept the types you wish to compare. Anyway:

```
public <C extends Vehicle> void generateDiff(Class<C> type, C original, C copy);
```

And you can use it as such:

```
generateDiff(Plane.class, new Plane(), new Plane()); // OK
generateDiff(Car.class, new Car(), new Car()); // OK
generateDiff(Plane.class, new Plane(), new Car()); // ERROR
generateDiff(Vehicle.class, new Plane(), new Car()); // OK
```

Not sure why any sane person would want to do this though! :)

Comment: +1 for `Not sure why any sane person would want to do this though! :)`

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible in my opinion, any method which can accept Vehicle as an argument will be able to accept CAR and PLANE. Since compiler dont know what kind of Objects will come(can be CAR, BUS, PLANE), it cannot guarentee that two params are of exactly same type. If some one extends CAR and creates a FORD? both objects are type CAR.

Only way to ensure this is at runtime using custom logic.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, the answer to your question is 'no, it's not possible'.

However, there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9938089/774444). Create a method `<T extends Vehicle> VehicleDiffer<T> compare(T vehicleA)` where `VehicleDiffer<T>` has a method `ReturnType with(T vehicleB)`. Now you can do the following calls:

```
compare(new Car()).with(new Car()); // okay
compare(new Plane()).with(new Plane()); // okay
```

The following will fail:

```
compare(new Car()).with(new Plane()); // with(Car) can't be called with argument type Plane
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't be achieved with or without generics.  Essentially, you are asking if you can tell the compiler to violate the rules of polymorphism.

Even if you explicitly defined a method without generics, like the one below, it would still accept any pair of classes which extend `Vehicle`.

```
void generateDiff(Vehicle maybePlane, Vehicle maybeCar) { ...
```

There is one scenario that is an exception, but I wouldn't recommend it.  If you are calling the method against `final` class objects (or any class that is not extended) that extend `Vehicle`, you can override the method to match that class' signature for each parameter.  But you need to define each one explicitly.

```
class Vehicle;
final class Car extends Vehicle;
final class Plane extends Vehicle;

void generateDiff(Car car1, Car car2) { ...
void generateDiff(Plane plane1, Plane plane2) { ...

generateDiff(new Car(), new Car()); // OK
generateDiff(new Plane(), new Plane()); // OK
generateDiff(new Car(), new Plane()); // No matching method
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I achive this at compile time using Generics?

Nope because the types are set at run time, but you can simply use introspection and throw an exception if an invalid type is sent to the function, though if thats the case then they maybe theres a flaw in your design, but thats just my opinion.

`instanceof` operator will check what the underlying type, and so you can raise an exception or do something more appropriate.

```
public <T extends Vehicle> generateDiff(T original, T copy)
```

since you may be comparing different types, maybe you shouldn't have a single function, since it would require a fair amount of `if else` it may be wiser to implement the function correspondingly in each class so they can properly compare with objects of the appropriate type, though Im taking a fair amount assumptions, which may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible!

This is what I would do:

```
class Vehicle;
class Car extends Vehicle;
class Plane extends Vehicle;

class DiffGenerator {
  public Diff generateDiff(Car original, Car copy) {
    return generateDiff(original, copy)
  }

  public Diff generateDiff(Plane original, Plane copy) {
    return generateDiff(original, copy)
  }

  private Diff generateDiff(Vehicle original, Vehicle copy) {
    return generatedDiff;
  }

}
```

Noticed the private method? `private Diff generateDiff(Vehicle original, Vehicle copy)`